# How to use linear color attachment with NV extension in vulkan?

Tags: vulkan, image

I have an OptiX ray tracer and a Vulkan renderer. In Vulkan, so far I have only been displaying the image the ray tracer created.
Now I want to add rendering in the Vulkan renderer.

For the interop, I created a VkImage with linear tiling, such that I can write to the image's buffer in OptiX. This works fine, but I cannot change the linear tiling (I believe), as otherwise OptiX would probably write garbage (or rather Vulkan would interpret garbage from the OptiX buffer writing).

Currently I want to add drawing lines in Vulkan, so my approach was: Use the image shared between OptiX and Vulkan as a framebuffer and render lines to it with a new graphics pipeline.
However, this requires the image to have usage `VK_IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT`. This is prohibited when having a linear tiling image in the specs, the validation layers tell me as much.

Now there is this NVidia extension about having a linear color attachment: https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VK_NV_linear_color_attachment.html
So this looks like a solution to me. But I can't get it to work.

My image's format is `VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_SFLOAT`. I have queried support:

```
VkFormatProperties3 formatProperties3{};
formatProperties3.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_FORMAT_PROPERTIES_3;
VkFormatProperties2 formatProperties2{};
formatProperties2.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_FORMAT_PROPERTIES_2;
formatProperties2.pNext = &formatProperties3;

vkGetPhysicalDeviceFormatProperties2(Device->PhysicalDevice,
VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_SFLOAT, &formatProperties2);

if (formatProperties3.linearTilingFeatures &     
    VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_2_LINEAR_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT_NV)
{
    // this is reached, so is supported
}
```

I have also set the device feature when creating the logical device:

```
physicalDeviceFeatures.pNext = &otherFeature;

VkPhysicalDeviceLinearColorAttachmentFeaturesNV linearColorAttachmentFeature{};
linearColorAttachmentFeature.sType =
    VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_LINEAR_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_FEATURES_NV;
otherFeature.pNext = &linearColorAttachmentFeature;
vkGetPhysicalDeviceFeatures2(Device->PhysicalDevice, &physicalDeviceFeatures);

vkGetPhysicalDeviceFeatures2(physicalDevice, &physicalDeviceFeatures);

VkDeviceCreateInfo createInfo{};
createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO;
// ...
createInfo.pNext = &physicalDeviceFeatures;
VkResult result = vkCreateDevice(physicalDevice, &createInfo, nullptr, &device);
```

From what I understand, this should already enable using a linear tiling image with color attachment bit. However, when I create the image view, I still get the following error in my validation layers:

> Validation Layer(ERROR):        Validation Error: [ VUID-VkImageViewCreateInfo-usage-02276 ] Object 0: handle = 0xf443490000000006, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_IMAGE; | MessageID = 0x27cb6471 | vkCreateImageView(): pCreateInfo->format VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_SFLOAT with tiling VK_IMAGE_TILING_LINEAR does not support usage that includes VK_IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT. The Vulkan spec states: If usage contains VK_IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT, then the image view's format features must contain VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.250.1/windows/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkImageViewCreateInfo-usage-02276)

Therefore the question: How to use the linear color attachment extension for NVidia?